# Cant find Paypal custom payment pages

Tags: paypal

I made a client site 'SSL' several weeks ago that used Paypal so was able to show a custom image on the paypal payment screen as it came from a secure source. However I just made another site SSL and intended to do the same and I simply cant find the 'custom payment pages' option in the paypal control panel where it was previously. Before it was along with 'My selling preferences' > 'Selling online' directly below 'Website preferences' but I've hunted high and low for the same option and cant find it. Looked on google with no luck so wondering if any paypal gurus out there would know where they have moved it to or a workaround to achieve same effect?

Answer (score 2):

Login first to your PayPal account and then click/load this direct link to the custom pages: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-page-styles

Comment: you could mark this as the correct answer -- solved it for me. thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to reach this page through the menus?

Comment: So, the same question for me. How to reach this page through the menus ?

Comment: Log into your PayPal account and navigate to your custom page payment pages:

Click the Profile icon at the top right of your PayPal admin area
Click Profile and settings in the dropdown
Click My selling tools in the left navigation bar
Locate Custom payment pages in the Selling online section and click the associated Update link

....but seems PayPal removed the option "Custom payment pages" for some reason !

Answer (score 0):

1. First check that your SSL certificate has not expired.
2. Pass the `image_url` parameter to pass a custom logo or banner.

   - if calling PayPal with the GET method 
     from an anchor `<a href="...">Buy this</a>` :
     append `&image_url=https://your-custom-banner.jpeg` to the linked URL.
   - if calling PayPal from a form, with the POST method:
     `<input name="image_url" value="https://your-custom-banner.jpeg" />`